# Excluding date(s) from a report

Tags: t-sql

Monday this week (26th August) was a public holiday in the UK. I need to exclude this date from some of my reports.

Simple enough but I have one database where the date is broken into 15 minute segments, for example:

2019-08-26 08:30:00.000

2019-08-26 16:15:00.000

The only way I can work out to exclude all these dates from the report would be to use NOT IN, for example:

```sql
AND a.mydate NOT IN ('2019-08-26 08:30:00.000', '2019-08-26 16:15:00.000')
```

Which seems quite a ponderous way of doing it to me.

There's also:

```sql
and a.mydate NOT BETWEEN '2019-08-26 08:30:00.000' and '2019-08-26 19:30:00.000'
```

but any advance on that would be useful to know about, if there is an advance on this, as there will be more, perhaps many more, public holidays to exclude, moving forwards.

I do not have a separate table with holiday dates in it, so I need to script as per the above.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked better:

```
and cast(a.mydate as date) not in 

   (  '2019-08-26', 

      '2019-12-25', 

      '2019-12-26',

      '2020-01-01',

       . . .  )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have discreet values, you could add them to a table and do a left join and put a filter in `WHERE` saying the exclusion table's Id should be null (meaning the join failed).

Sth like:

```
SELECT 
       mydata
FROM
       mytable mt LEFT JOIN Holidays h ON mt.mydate = h.date
WHERE
       h.Id IS NULL
```

This is just an alternative way made possible because you have discrete values, I'm not sure if it's actually faster or not...

Comment: Thanks - yes, apologies, I just amended my post to say I don't have a separate table for holidays (nor the permissions to create one) - appreciate your reply.